# How to filter Projects by custom fields in OpenAsset API v1

Tags: rest

I am looking to filter a query for Projects by custom user fields (Field objects) using OpenAsset REST API v1

I find the documentation to be incomplete, or at least lacking examples. Currently I am unable to filter Projects by custom fields. I can see the fields populated on the Projects by querying /Projects?fields=all but any attempt to use the filterBy is not working, I have tried other filter options but they didn't work, although I'll admit I may have used them incorrectly.

[**The documentation says**](https://developers.openasset.com/#advanced-filters) that there are advanced "filterBy" options that allow one to pass an object, array or JSON string to filter using complex rules.

Here is an example of the currently returned Projects object:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fields": [
            {
                "id": 46,
                "values": [
                    "N"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**I am trying to select projects that have a custom field id 46 equal to a values[] of "Y"**

This is my query so far: `{{base_url}}/Projects/?fields=all&filterBy={"fields": {"values": "Y"}}`

Any help is appreciated

Other queries I tried:

- `{{base_url}}/Projects/?displayFields=id&fields=all&filterBy={fields: [{values: "Y"}]}`
- `{{base_url}}/Projects/?displayFields=id&fields=all&filterBy={"fields": [{"id": 46}, {"values": "Y"}]}`
- `{{base_url}}/Projects/?fields=46&values[]=Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to discover the correct filtering pattern required to filter on fields:

`{{base_url}}/Projects?filterBy[-and][0][show_on_website]=*Y*`

the field I wanted to filter on had a rest_code value of `show_on_website`, using this and the correct filtering format gave me the result I needed.